# Incorrectly setup VirtualHosts, trying to fix

Tags: apache-2.2

I've inherited the job of sorting out our servers for a major application that we run. Our main location for the domain has got a SSL cert on it, and this is running fine.

The problem begins to arise when we visit https:// versions of the other applications on the server, as these then try to use the VirtualHost for the main application.

**Example:**

> https:/main.application.co.uk - Works fine as this has a VirtualHost for 443.
>
> http:/secondary.application.co.uk - Works fine as it is not using port 443.
>
> https:/secondary.application.co.uk - Try and uses VirtualHost for main.application as they sit on the same IP and is trying to use 443.

So in effect, visiting the https://secondary.application.co.uk, give's you https://main.application.co.uk but with a warning before you enter the site.

My question being: *Is there a way to setup a default VirtualHost for :443 which will handle these requests, and potentially 404 them, or redirect them to the non http versions?*

Server Madness!

<sub>Disclaimer: This was not my fault! And also I've realised I used single /'s in the URLs.</sub>

Comment: I dont understand your request very well. Why do you need secondary.application?

Comment: It's a different application which is hosted on the same server.